# Can Google Analytics track Custom Events from an AdWords Flash Banner?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-ads-api

i know it can track flash events from other flash banners/sites on other networks..
but can it from Adwords?

i found this code:

```
on (release) {
// Track with no action
getURL("javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/folder/file.html');");
}
```

but it seems to require a JS script on the page.

how does Adwords handle this?

thanks

-art

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy to try this and upload a banner to AdWords, but the following seems to imply that this is not allowed

http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=28427&topic=28431

"Extra calls: Your ad code cannot make external server calls for additional JavaScript or other functionality. All functionality must be localized to the code itself. "

Also if you want to use Google Analytics within Flash, refer to the following documentation :

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingIntro.html

(in your case it sounds like Bridge mode is what you are looking for).

Comment: BridgeMode is for when u have access to the html and page environment..so that wont work. but the other AS3 option seemingly will. will test.. thanks

Comment: Yes, you're  right - AS3 mode - sorry. Let me know how it goes.